# Call order refer to some information

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, queue, call

now I have `std::map<std::string, Object> myMap`. Class `Object` has funcions: `int getPriority()` and `void Work()`. Now I go through the map and want to call `Work` due to the priority of object.

I wrote very crazy idea: the clone of that map, but it stores in the key it's priority, for example:

```
myMap["3_key1"] = Object();
myMap["6_key2"] = Object();
myMap["0_key3"] = Object();
```

It sorts and calling is in right queue: `0_key3; 3_key1; 6_key2`.

But this is very slow, I think. And I want to replace `std::map` with `unordered_map` from **boost** because it's a lot faster. And there isn't sorting by key.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Can I ask why you think it is slow?

Comment: And, also, do you know which operations of `unordered_map` are faster than the standard `map`?

Comment: @GMan yes. @kiril-kirov simple insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html):

```
// your class
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class foo
{
public:
    foo(std::string name, unsigned priority, std::string msg) :
    mPriority(priority)
    {
        mName.swap(name); // primitive std::move :)
        mMsg.swap(msg); // (default-construct & swap)
    }

    const std::string& name() const
    {
        return mName;
    }

    unsigned priority() const
    {
        return mPriority;
    }

    void work() const
    {
        std::cout << mMsg << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string mName;

    unsigned mPriority;
    std::string mMsg;
};

// your container
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

typedef boost::multi_index_container<foo,
            bmi::indexed_by<
                // order by name (std::map)
                bmi::ordered_unique<
                    bmi::const_mem_fun<foo, const std::string&, &foo::name>
                        >,

                // order by priority (std::multi_map)
                bmi:: ordered_non_unique<
                    bmi::const_mem_fun<foo, unsigned ,&foo::priority>
                        >
                > 
            > foo_set;

// test
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int main()
{
    foo_set fooSet;
    fooSet.insert(foo("a", 4, "this is a, priority 4"));
    fooSet.insert(foo("b", 3, "this is b, priority 3"));
    fooSet.insert(foo("c", 7, "this is c, priority 7"));
    fooSet.insert(foo("d", 1, "this is c, priority 1"));

    // view as map from name to value
    foo_set::nth_index<0>::type& nameView = fooSet.get<0>();

    nameView.find("a")->work(); // find "a", print its message
    if (nameView.find("e") == nameView.end())
        std::cerr << "e not found" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // view as multi_map from priority to value
    foo_set::nth_index<1>::type& priorityView = fooSet.get<1>();

    BOOST_FOREACH(const foo& f, priorityView)
        f.work(); // work, in order of priority
}
```

I don't have any performance tests on it, but it certainly better expresses your intent, and that's usually indicative of improved performance anyway.

Comment: Great answer. However, as always :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is two containers. Your current key->value map, and a second heap of keys that orders by priority of the object (possibly just use `priority_queue` as your heap implementation). This would have difficulties of priority can change on the fly though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use std::set or std::priority_queue instead of std::map, you can define a functor, or simply implement operator< for your class so that the std::set orders the objects in priority order for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Object {
  public:
    int m_priority;

    Object(int p) : m_priority(p) { }

    int getPriority() const { return m_priority; }

    void Work() const { std::cout << m_priority << std::endl; }
};

bool operator<(const Object & lhs, const Object & rhs)
{
    return lhs.getPriority() < rhs.getPriority();
}

int main()
{
    std::set<Object> container;

    container.insert(Object(1));
    container.insert(Object(9));
    container.insert(Object(5));
    container.insert(Object(8));
    container.insert(Object(3));

    for (std::set<Object>::iterator I = container.begin();
         I != container.end();
         ++I) {
        I->Work();
    }
}
```